# Im not understand what i have to change in sql big query

Tags: google-bigquery

what i have to do  if No matching signature for operator / for argument types: STRUCT<INT64, INT64>, INT64. Supported signatures: FLOAT64 / FLOAT64;

I'm hoping i can get some enlightenment